# Removing white space from URL Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, openpyxl

I have a URL that has white space in the beginning. I have to remove it before passing it to **urllib.request.urlretrieve**.

```
pdflink = '﻿ https://www.doj.nh.gov/consumer/security-breaches/documents/a2z-field-services-20201218.pdf'
```

But, I am not able to remove it.

What I have tried till now:

1. `pdflink.lstrip()` : not working and I do not know why?
2. `pdflink.replace(' ', '')` : not working

Any idea how to remove it?

My final code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Final']

pdflink = (ws.cell(row=4487,column=4).value).lstrip()

# pdflink will have value as shown below:
#pdflink = '﻿ https://www.doj.nh.gov/consumer/security-breaches/documents/a2z-field-services-20201218.pdf'
try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdflink, 'test')
        return True
except FileNotFoundError:
        print(filename + ' Not present')
        return False
```

Running above code will throw error as:
**URLError: urlopen error unknown url type: ﻿ https**

**Root cause of the error**: Additional white space in the beginning of the URL.

Comment: What does `print(ord(pdflink[0]))` print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just a space.  You have some non-printing special character in there as the first character.  I can't tell which one, but when I cut-and-paste from your post, I get an extra character.  You might try `print(ord(pdflink[0]))` to see what it is.  You may need to use `pdflink = pdflink[2:]` to clean it out.  Or, search for the `http`:

```
    i = pdflink.find('http')
    pdflink = pdflink[i:]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and great explanation. This works perfectly in combination with opepyxl.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a unicode character `FEFF` in that link prior to the space.  You can't see it, but it is breaking your `lstrip`

You can see it [here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%27%EF%BB%BF%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.doj.nh.gov%2Fconsumer%2Fsecurity-breaches%2Fdocuments%2Fa2z-field-services-20201218.pdf%27)

I would suggest using `pdflink.split(' ')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

There's possibly some weird character at the beginning of the string - I would try to open the file you're trying to read with specified `encoding="UTF-8"`.

I also solved this issue using `pdflink.lstrip("﻿ ")` where inside the quotes I copy-pasted that non-space thing from your original string